# What happens behind MATLAB's factor() function?

Tags: matlab, primes, factorization

Mainly, why is it so fast (for big numbers)? The documentation only tells me how to use it. For example, it needs at most one second to find the largest prime factor of 1234567890987654, which, to me, seems insane.

```
>>max(factor(1234567890987654))

ans =

    69444443
```

Comment: The function is implemented with a simple sieve approach. You can look at implementation details if you type 'edit factor'.

Comment: @gregswiss That's it! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

The largest factor to be tried is sqrt(N), or 35136418 in this case. Also even the most elementary optimizations would skip all even numbers > 2, leaving only 17568209 candidates to be tested. Once the candidate 17777778 (and it's cofactor 69444443) is found, the algorithm would be wise enough to stop.

This can be somewhat easily improved further by a modified sieve to skip multiples of small primes 2,3,5[,7].

Basically even the sqrt(N) optimization is enough for the noted performance, unless you are working on an exceptionally old CPU (8086).

Comment: Do you know of a possibility to see "into" the underlying Matlab script?

Comment: `help factor` in Octave lead to "/usr/share/octave/3.2.4/m/specfun/factor.m" -- and this algorithm is rather inefficient.

Comment: The problem with factor.m in Octave is basically that it generates all primes(sqrt(n)) in advance. For a worst case this is good, but most numbers have small factors, which factored out would quickly lead to generating a much smaller set of candidates.

Answer (score 2):

It's interesting to look at the source code of the `factor` and `primes` functions.

`factor(N)` essentiallty calls `primes` to find out all primes up to `sqrt(N)`. Once they have been identified, it tests them one by one to see if they divide `N`.

`primes(n)` uses [Eratosthenes' sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes): for each identified prime, remove all its multiples, [exploiting `sqrt` again](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Computational_analysis) to reduce complexity.